# GoogleMyBusiness API : Unknow name websiteUrl at location : cannot find field

Tags: php, api, google-my-business-api

I'm using Google MyBusiness API (v4), and i'm trying to update websiteurl of my locations.

But i get this error "Unknow name websiteUrl at location : cannot find field"

I check the doc, and the field is "websiteUrl", so what's wrong ?

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

I check the lib, i check the code and i check the doc, the field is websiteUrl

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method has been deprecated, please use the new Business Information API, note that the field has been renamed to websiteUri.

Model:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations

Patch method:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/patch

Comment: Actually I already use the new Business Information API, not the V4 (I made a mistake when writing my message).
But I did not change websiteUrl to websiteUri.....
Thanks for putting light on that simple issue